# Estimate Naive - Bayes probability function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I keep having problems with Matlab translation to Python. I have code in Matlab I've written last year (working) and now try to translate the functions to Python. 5 of them work, 4 don't. I'm really stuck and would love some help. 
This one is about estimating Naive-Bayes probability. Here is the function in Matlab:

```
function [ p_x_y ] = estimate_p_x_y_NB(Xtrain,ytrain,a,b )

% Function calculates probability distribution p(x|y), assuming that x is binary
% and its elements are independent from each other

% Xtrain - training dataset NxD
% ytrain - training dataset class labels 1xN
% p_x_y - binomial distribution estimators - element at position(m,d)
% represents estimator p(x_d=1|y=m) MxD
% N - number of elements in training dataset
D = size(Xtrain,2);
M = length(unique(ytrain));
p_x_y = zeros(M,D);
for i=1:M
    for j=1:D
        numerator = sum((ytrain==i).*((Xtrain(:,j)==1))')+a-1;
        denominator = sum(ytrain==i)+a+b-2;
        p_x_y(i,j) = numerator/denominator;
    end
end
end
```

This is my translation to Python:

```
def estimate_p_x_y_nb(Xtrain, ytrain, a, b):
    """
    :param Xtrain: training data NxD
    :param ytrain: class labels for training data 1xN
    :param a: parameter a of Beta distribution
    :param b: parameter b of Beta distribution
    :return: Function calculated probality p(x|y) assuming that x takes binary values and elements
    x are independent from each other. Function returns matrix p_x_y that has size MxD.
    """
    D = Xtrain.shape[1]
    M = len(np.unique(ytrain))
    p_x_y = np.zeros((M, D))
    for i in range (M):
        for j in range(D):
            up = np.sum((ytrain == i+1).dot((Xtrain[:, j]==1)).conjugate().T) + a - 1
            down = np.sum((ytrain == i+1) + a + b -2)
            p_x_y[i,j] = up/down
    return p_x_y
```

Traceback:

```
    p_x_y[i,j] = up/down
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If you can see any problems with the function, I'd be super happy to have it pointed out. Also, I used `.dot` instead of just `*` in the `up` variable since when it was `*`, I got an error about inaccurate dimensions, but with this one, it seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the results from the MATLAB code to what is obtained by Python in each line to see where the problem is? Its an easy way to narrow down your problem. Or provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Replacing the element-wise product `.*` with dot-protuct `dot` is likely wrong. The element-wise product in numpy is `*`.

Comment: @kazemakase alright, so you're saying it should probably stay * ? (in python?). Yet when I leave it that way, I get a "ValueError: dimension mismatch". I suppose it's because of the transpose later on, but it works in Matlab :(

Comment: Yep. Use `*` and find the cause of the error rather than make the symptoms go away with `dot` :) I don't know what's causing the error - it will depend on the shapes of your arrays. Most likely it is due to different broadcasting rules in Matlab and Python. Take the expression apart to find out what exactly is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in the statement where you are assigning the denominator. You have made a wrong use of brackets

> down = np.sum((ytrain == i+1) + a + b -2)

should be

```
down = np.sum((ytrain == i+1)) + a + b -2
```

Also, try to change

> up = np.sum((ytrain == i+1).dot((Xtrain[:, j]==1)).conjugate().T) + a - 1

to

```
up = np.sum((ytrain == i+1) * (Xtrain[:, j]==1)) + a - 1
```

I hope that works. I don't see any other problems with your code.

After the change, I used the values

```
Xtrain = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])
ytrain = np.array([1,2])
a = 1
b = 1
```

This gave the output as

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

in both MATLAB and python. You can check using these values if the outcome is as expected.

Comment: thank you, didn't notice that! changed it, but my program still errors on up/down, unfortunately

Comment: I agree with this ammportal, when I changed the python code to `down = np.sum((ytrain == i+1)) + a + b -2` I got the same answer in python as in matlab.

Comment: @Lin K For me after this change there is no error. Are you sure that your code is correct and there is nothing else that interferes with it? I have edited my answer to show the output I am getting.

Comment: I checked the code so many times I have it memorized, I don't know why isn't it working :( I have to implement functions only and they have to be 'approved' by the program so I can't input my own values. Yet everything looks in order to me too, and whether I leave .dot or change it to *, I still get an error. This is killing me. Thank you very much though!

Comment: I think there might be another mistake in your code. I have made another change in the answer.